# Dismiss all Detail Views when switching Tabs on TabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

My iOS app has:

```
TabBarController
    NavigationController1
        TableView1
            ViewController1 (Details View)
    NavigationController2
        TableView2
            ViewController2 (Details View)
```

[image: My Ap]
**Behavior:**

- When the app loads, I see the TableView1.
- I select an Item in the table, and it takes me via Show (Push) segue the details view 1.
- I switch to the second tab on the bottom, and see TableView2.
- I select an item and it takes me to details view 2
- I navigate back to first tab, and see details view 1

**Desired:**

When performing last step, I'd like to dismiss the details view and see the first TableView1, and when switching back to second tab, I want that one to be dismissed and to see the table view.

I've tried different combinations of `dismissViewControllerAnimated` and `popToRootViewControllerAnimated` but I just don't seem to figure it out.

**MainTabBarController.h**

```
@interface MainTabBarController : UITabBarController <UITabBarControllerDelegate>
```

**MainTabBarController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.delegate = self;
}
...
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{
    // NSLog Works fine, and displays information in the output
    NSLog (@"%@ %lu", tabBarController.selectedViewController.title, tabBarController.selectedIndex);

    // None of the lines below achieve the desired result
    [viewController.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [viewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    [tabBarController.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [tabBarController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: See my updated answer based on the code you added.

Comment: @Dmytro See my update with code snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to make use of the `UITabBarControllerDelegate`. Listen for changes to the tab selection. Based on the new tab, get the tab's navigation controller and call its `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:` method.

Update based on the code added to the question:

The problem is with how you try to pop the view controllers. You want this:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{
    // NSLog Works fine, and displays information in the output
    NSLog (@"%@ %lu", tabBarController.selectedViewController.title, tabBarController.selectedIndex);

    // If the selected tab's root controller is a navigation controller
    // pop to the top view controller in the tab's navigation stack
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
        UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *)viewController;
        [nav popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do, but it just doesn't seem to pop back to root view controller. The didSelectViewController method works fine, I get the proper NSLog output, but the popToRootViewControllerAnimated just doesn't do anything. I tried calling it on several different objects available in the scope of the function, but nothing worked :( Now I'm not sure I even declared the delegate properly...

Comment: Update your question with the relevant code. Then someone can help you find the issue.

Comment: I knew I was missing something simple, thanks for finally clearing this whole thing out! Works like a charm ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution for this.

Try to implement the following methods of UIViewContorller

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated; // Called when the view is dismissed, covered or otherwise hidden. Default does nothing
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated;  // Called after the view was dismissed, covered or otherwise hidden. Default does nothing
```

1. Go to your detail-1 view controller and implement the method `- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated`.
   Do a pop for that controller.
2. Same you should do for the detail-2

Here is the code snippet that will help you.

In **Appdelegate.m**

```
@interface AppDelegate ()<UITabBarControllerDelegate>

@property(nonatomic, strong) MainTabBarController *rootTabBarController;

@end

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    self.rootTabBarController = [[MainTabBarController alloc]init];
    self.rootTabBarController.delegate = self;
    self.window.rootViewController = self.rootTabBarController;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

}
```

**TabBarController delegate implementation**

```
-(void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    NSUInteger index = [self.rootTabBarController.viewControllers indexOfObject:viewController];
    NSLog(@"Index : %lu", (unsigned long)index);

    switch (index) {
        case 0:
            // pop other tab barcontrollers pushed or modal windows
            [self.rootTabBarController flushViewControllerStackForIndex:1];
            break;

        case 1:
            [self.rootTabBarController flushViewControllerStackForIndex:0];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

**MainTabBarController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    [self setViewControllers:@[
                               [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[FirstViewController alloc]init]],
                               [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[SecondViewController alloc]init]]
                               ] animated:YES];
}

-(void)flushViewControllerStackForIndex:(NSUInteger )index {

    [[self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:index] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];  
}
```

Here is screenshot in sequence for the sample I ran.

[image]

Here is the [Sample code.](https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/problem-arc/SimpleTab.zip)

That should solve your purpose & is the right approach.

Now you may need to fine tune your own logic in `flushViewControllerStackForIndex` to check if there is just only controller being pushed on stack or a combination of push & modal. So better try to navigate on the Stack & **do-a-dismiss-if-a-modal** or **do-a-pop-if-a-push**.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is a good one! Literally looking at my problem from the opposite side. I just wonder if it's possible to determine WHAT is covering the Detail-1/2 view controller. Let's say I have an image gallery on the details view controller and tapping on individual images will take me to yet another view where I can see full screen images and scroll through them. When users hit back, I assume they'd want to see the Details view, and not the list.

Comment: That's up to you to decide which is Detail1/2. :-)
Here is an update on the basic idea that you needed to achieve the behavior of your app while switching between tabs.

Comment: Wow, this is a very interesting solution, although I'm glad to see that in the end it still uses the function I originally had question about. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can directly set the view controllers currently on the navigation stack. All you have to is directly set the viewControllers property of the navigation controllers when switch tabs in the tabbar controller.

Set NavigationController1.viewcontrollers = @[tableView1] when you switch to tab1